# Find out whether specific rake task is currently running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

Is there any way to find out whether particular rake task is currently running from Rails controller for example? I have an extensive rake task, which takes 5-6 hours to finish.

I need to see status of that rake task from frontend web interface, like:

- Task "some operation" is running...

Also it would be nice to be able to hard stop / run that rake task from within frontend web interface.

If found [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background) devoted to it, but the method described there allows only to run rake task from controller, but not to stop/see its status.

Comment: r u using something like `resque` or `sidekiq` to run jobs in background?

Comment: No, but after a quick look into it, it might be just what I need

Comment: Exactly. You will be able to find status using one of these

Comment: I have explained our conversation in the form of answer. So that other devs can take benefit from that. You can also accept and close the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your job is taking 5-6 hours to complete, you must run it in background. To run long running jobs in background you can use one of these:

1. [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque)
2. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

And for tracking status of your jobs, you can use corresponding status tracking gems:

1. [ResqueStatus](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status)
2. [SidekiqStatus](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status)

Personally, I prefer sidekiq for its efficiency.

NOTE: All the above mentioned gems has good enough docs. Kindly refer to those.

Comment: I tried both rescue and sidekiq, and sidekiq seems easier to install and get up and running. Also it has nice dashboard