# How to check if a rake task is running ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

so is there a way to check if a rake task is running or finished?

I reviewed around and all I found were these 2 answers, and none of those seems to be a good fit for my particular problem, I am running one rake task (only need to run it once), but because of the nature of the operations performed by the rake task it takes some time to finish (more than ~8h), so I was wondering if might be some way to check if the task finished the execution (besides adding some logs). One of the answers is to use Sidekiq but I don't want to wrap up everything in a cronjob since I only need to run it once, the other answer said that there is no such thing but is from 3 years ago.

[3 years ago answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140835/how-to-check-if-rake-task-was-finished)

[cronjob answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710271/find-out-whether-specific-rake-task-is-currently-running)

Thx in advance!

Comment: What does your rake task do? Is there any logging or file creation that you can check for?

Comment: thx for the response @Sara Tibbetts, yup I can add logging, but I was wondering if there is something like a command from rake, and no, no file creation only operations over a db

Comment: Aren't rake tasks synchronous? So you could call it from shell, and fire some other shell command when its done?

Comment: Use a database table (plus Rail model) to track the task executions. Maybe with `started_at`, `finished_at`, and `pid`.

Comment: the problem @max pleaner is that the task is running in a virtual machine (on a cluster) and my connection is not too good is likely that I am going to lose my connection => so the shell window is going to get closed

Comment: thx for the response @max pleaner

Comment: @Stefan thx for the response, is only one time task, so I do prefer not to create a table for it, I think it might be better add some logs to the task, is weird there is no command or something to check this

Comment: I see, seems like I misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: feel free to edit if you think that will helps to get an answer @Stefan, and thx again for the response

Comment: Rake is really just a DSL for writing Make like instructions and a simple runner that lets you run tasks in multiple threads. It does not actually have any kind of monitoring but you can write out PID's to a file (or somewhere else) and use tools such as px to check the status of the process. https://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html

Comment: There are also more sophisticated monitoring solutions like [God](https://github.com/mojombo/god), [AppSignal](https://docs.appsignal.com/ruby/integrations/rake.html) and [New Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/background-jobs/rake-instrumentation).

Comment: thx for the response @max